# form.onsumbit subclass

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i write smart extension for chrome and I inject my javascript inside all frame in frameset page...

In one of frame I want to replace onsumbit for form.
I want to analyze (x, y) values for image type field before make submit.

I can find element by name to get form.
I can get onsubmit property.
But how to make check sending values before submit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, something like this?

```
var formEl = document.getElementById("form1");

var originalOnSubmit = formEl.onsubmit;

formEl.onsubmit = function() {
    if(all_ok) {
        originalOnSubmit();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```